# DTB parsing questions on format

Tags: c, device-tree

Good day,

I am currently working on a simple DTB parser in C to use it in my own hypervisor and I think I am missing something in the documentation.

Here is a hexadecimal view of:

```
00000000  D0 0D FE ED 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 1D 7C   ...........@...|
00000010  00 00 00 30 00 00 00 11 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00   ...0............
00000020  00 00 01 F1 00 00 1D 3C 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   .......<........
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00000040  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04   ................
00000050  00 00 00 BA 00 00 80 05 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 11   ................
00000060  00 00 00 26 6C 69 6E 75 78 2C 64 75 6D 6D 79 2D   ...&linux,dummy-
00000070  76 69 72 74 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04   virt............
00000080  00 00 00 1A 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04   ................
00000090  00 00 00 0B 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 11   ................
000000A0  00 00 00 00 6C 69 6E 75 78 2C 64 75 6D 6D 79 2D   ....linux,dummy-
000000B0  76 69 72 74 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 70 73 63 69   virt........psci
000000C0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 01 E9   ................
000000D0  C4 00 00 05 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 01 E2   ................
000000E0  C4 00 00 03 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 01 DA   ................
000000F0  84 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 01 CE   ................
```

Let me remind here some definitions from the documentation, specifically the definitions of the tokens:

**FDT_BEGIN_NODE (0x00000001)**

**FDT_END_NODE (0x00000002)**

**FDT_PROP (0x00000003)**

**FDT_NOP (0x00000004)**

**FDT_END (0x00000009)**

So we can clearly tell using the version 17 of the DTB documentation that, the header is set and is set correctly.

The offset to struct field is 40. So lets start parsing the / node:
We first get the token FDT_BEGIN_NODE which marks the beginning of a node’s representation. It
shall be followed by the node’s unit name as extra data. The name is stored as a null-terminated string, and shall
include the unit address (see section 2.2.1), if any. The node name is followed by zeroed padding bytes, if necessary
for alignment, and then the next token, which may be any token except FDT_END. However here it is followed by a zero? I don't see how and why this is possible.

Lets continue: We than get FDT_PROP so the next 32bit value is suppose to be the property length, and the one after the property length is the nameoff. However that does not seem to be the case...

I am very confused about the format, especially for this first node, however at one point it gets logical and the parser I currently wrote (that respects the version 17 documentation) starts to get the nodes correctly, let me show you this place in the DTB:

```
00000140  63 69 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 6D 65 6D 6F   ci..........memo
00000150  72 79 40 34 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 00 00 00 00 03   ry@40000000.....
00000160  00 00 00 10 00 00 00 A7 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00   ............@...
00000170  00 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 07   ................
00000180  00 00 00 8D 6D 65 6D 6F 72 79 00 73 00 00 00 02   ....memory.s....
00000190  00 00 00 01 70 6C 61 74 66 6F 72 6D 2D 62 75 73   ....platform-bus
000001A0  40 63 30 30 30 30 30 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03   @c000000........
000001B0  00 00 00 04 00 00 00 BA 00 00 80 05 00 00 00 03   ................
000001C0  00 00 00 10 00 00 00 F1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
000001D0  0C 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04   ................
000001E0  00 00 00 0B 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04   ................
000001F0  00 00 00 1A 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 19   ................
00000200  00 00 00 00 71 65 6D 75 2C 70 6C 61 74 66 6F 72   ....qemu,platfor
00000210  6D 00 73 69 6D 70 6C 65 2D 62 75 73 00 00 00 03   m.simple-bus....
00000220  00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 66 77 2D 63 66 67 40 39   ........fw-cfg@9
00000230  30 32 30 30 30 30 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00   020000..........
```

These nodes correspond perfectly to how the documentation describes it.

Can anyone explain in detail how I am supposed to parse the beginning of the DTB?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Offset 0x40 contains an FDT_BEGIN_NODE token. Offset 0x44 contains an empty name string (1 byte) and 3 padding bytes. Offset 0x48 contains an FDT_PROP token. Offset 0x4C contains the length 4 of the property. Offset 0x50 contains the offset 0xBA to the property name from the start of the strings block. The string block starts at offset 0x1D7C (as indicated by the value at offset 0xC), so the property name starts at offset 0x1D7C+0xBA=0x1E36. Offset 0x54 contains the property value bytes 0x00 0x00 0x80 0x05 (property values are just strings of raw bytes as far as FDT is concerned).